# What's the transposon difference between chimps and humans?

Tags: dna, dna-replication, genetic-code

I was reading that humans and chimps share 98-99% of the same DNA sequence but I also read humans and chimps only share around 20% of the same proteins. Also, 45% of the human genome is transposable elements, It's 42% reverse transposons and 3% DNA transposons.

So, I wanted to know the difference between humans and chimps when it comes to transposable elements, especially reverse transposons.

Sources added:

Eighty percent of proteins are different between humans and chimpanzees. [ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15716009](http://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15716009) and Retrotransposons - In mammals, almost half the genome (45% to 48%) is transposons or remnants of transposons. Around 42% of the human genome is made up of retrotransposons, while DNA transposons account for about 2–3%.[3] [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrotransposon][2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrotransposon)

Comment: Do you have a source for your numbers?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include the sources. Eighty percent of proteins are different between humans and chimpanzees. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15716009 and Retrotransposons -  In mammals, almost half the genome (45% to 48%) is transposons or remnants of transposons. Around 42% of the human genome is made up of retrotransposons, while DNA transposons account for about 2–3%.[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrotransposon

Comment: Note, saying "humans and chimps only share around 20% of the same proteins" is not quite right, the source you cite actually says that only 20% of proteins are *absolutely identical* - the remaining 80% are very similar, but have slight differences (based on the 1-2% difference in DNA sequence)